# Director Fury wants his CORE back, one of the Avengers stole it

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, story

I'm trying to add a bit of story to this riddle/puzzle, so blame me for trying!
I hope you like it, might be a bit rough at first, it's the first time I'm doing this myself. I enjoyed making it so good luck!

**Background story**:

You play a new character, whoever you want to be, but a superhero!
You are a new recruit to the Avengers. Director Fury just found out his CORE is missing. All of the Avenger-team members are missing, missing as in on vacation or on a mission. As you are a new member of the team since today you are going to have to help Fury with this problem.

**At the Avengers Headquarters**

Director Fury calls you to his office and so it begins:

> **Fury**: Hello new avenger, I'm director Fury.
>
> **You**: Hello director Fury.
>
> **Fury**: Come with me, it's urgent. This will be your first mission.
>
> *You walk to an office nearby where all camera footage is being kept.*
>
> **Fury**: The CORE has been stolen by one of our avengers. I believe he's working with Loki.
>
> **You**: Is he still kept captive?
>
> **Fury**: Yes, he's still in our dungeon. The thief didn't have much time to free Loki. I had a chat with Loki and he confirmed it's one of our avengers, sadly I believe him. Here's the footage of me chatting with Loki.

And so he shows you the video.

> *Click the video starts playing*
>
> **Fury**: What is so important right now that you have to tell me?!
>
> **Loki**: But Fury, don't be so mad, I know your CORE is missing...
>
> **Fury**: How would you know that?
>
> **Loki**: It was my plan after all, only the thief who stole your CORE  betrayed me.
>
> **Fury**: Why would I believe you. And if so tell me who did it!
>
> **Loki**: Well, ... one of your Avengers. *he said with an evil grin*
>
> **Fury**: I don't have time to play games Loki, tell me.
>
> **Loki**: Yet the thief did not free me, I still prefer him or her having the CORE over you. You don't like games Fury? Let's play one.
>
> **Fury**: I don't have time for this...
>
> **Loki**: Destruction is what I'm after. Remember this Fury ' +8+15-18-18+2-3+6-5+5-1-11 ' got it? Enjoy playing the game ha ha ha ha ... .
>
> *Click the video stopped playing*

The video stopped playing.
Director Fury addresses you once more.

> **Fury**: Son, as I don't have time to play games, you have to figure out what he means.
>
> **You**: I will do my best. Do you have any idea what these numbers mean?
>
> **Fury**: If I did I wouldn't ask you. You better figure it out!

So this will be your first mission. Figure out which Avenger stole the CORE.
Enjoy the game!

**Avengers Assemble!**

Comment: I have an idea that almost works but it requires the -15 to be +15 :(

Comment: @Lordofdark thanks, it had to be +15 indeed sorry! my bad :/

Comment: Are we *sure* Director Fury didn't steal the CORE and all of this isn't smoke and mirrors?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thief is

> Clint Barton (Hawkeye)

Because

> "Destruction is what I'm after"
>  We have to find the letters after "DESTRUCTION" using the shift "+8+15-18-18+2-3+6-5+5-1-11"
>  DESTRUCTION = 4 5 19 20 18 21 3 20 9 15 14
>  If you apply the shift modulo 26 you get these letters : LTABTRIONNC
>  You can re-arrange the letters to find CLINT BARTON

Comment: Thanks for finding the thief! You have earned your position at the Avengers Team!

Comment: I got as far as the shift, but was looking for the hero name, not the real name ... nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

My guess is:

> Captain America

Reason:

> If you add all the numbers the addition is -50 and there are 50 stars on the flag of America. Hence the answer could be Captain America.
>  Don't know why the "-" sign

Comment: This isn't the answer I'm looking for, also add >! to your answer so it's in a spoiler block so others don't instantly see it. But nice theory.

Comment: where to add this >!

Comment: @Shaan_B I've edited your post to add spoiler-tags. If you look at the changes I've made you can see `>! ` before your answers.

Comment: Looks like we all edited within 10 seconds of each other..

Comment: I guess it's a coincidence that it adds up to -50 haha. Nice theory though. That would have been a bit to easy wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Negative, becaues if you add 50 to -50 you destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not the right answer, but as it is tagged as lateral-thinking, I try :

> Loki lies and is the thief : if the told Avenger had to steal the CORE and then deliver Loki, but finally didn't come to deliver him, how could Loki know the Avenger has successfully stolen the CORE ?

Comment: It's not Loki :( there is some math you have to do. 
Loki worked with the thief but he betrayed him :(

Comment: Argh, OK, tried that because I was thinking the same than Gintas K at first

Comment: no problem keep trying! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The thief is

> Clint Barton, a.k.a Hawkeye. From a character point of view it would
>  be easy for Loki to get into his head, as he has done so once already,
>  but the series of numbers is a code for a shift cipher. Since Loki
>  says he is after 'destruction,' that's the word you want to apply the
>  cipher to. You have to shift all the letters over, and then you'll get
>  another series of letters. Then you just have to take those letters
>  and look for the letters making up the name of one of the Avengers.
>  You end up with Clint Barton.